# firebase cloud functions - no deployment error, but not executing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently started setting up firebase's cloud functions. I started with a simple helloWorld function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
console.log("hello from firebase");
});
```

I have set up npm, node.js, python 3.65, pip installed, and the functions appear in the console. It just says "0 executions" and nothing happens. I didnt get any error message.. "Successful operation" and "deploy complete".

Anyone got an idea why the function isnt being executed?

Comment: Deploying a function doesn't execute it. It will only be executed when you make a HTTP request to its URL. What did you do to trigger the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank said, deploying a function doesn't execute the function.  When you deploy an HTTP function, you will receive a URL for that function.  The function runs when that url is accessed.  On first deployment, that url is printed to the console.  After that, you can see the full url by going to the Firebase console and finding your list of functions.

Copy that url and paste it into your browser to see it work.

You can also follow this guide to getting [started with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! this video tutorial is way better than the written ones I read.